# Checking content of multiple input fields jQuery

Tags: jquery, crossword

I'm creating a basic crossword using input fields within an HTML table and am looking to check whether the answer is correct using jQuery. If the answer is correct I also need to open dialog X and if the answer is incorrect I need to open dialog Y.

Taking the code snippet below as an example ...

```
<td><input name="r1c1" type="text" id="r1c1-input" maxlength="1"></td>
<td><input name="r1c2" type="text" id="r1c2-input" maxlength="1"></td>
<td><input name="r1c3" type="text" id="r1c3-input" maxlength="1"></td>
<td><input name="r1c4" type="text" id="r1c4-input" maxlength="1"></td>
<td><input name="r1c5" type="text" id="r1c5-input" maxlength="1"></td>
```

... how would I check that the following had been typed in to each field?

r1c1 = A

r1c2 = B

r1c3 = C

r1c4 = D

r1c5 = E

Many thanks.

Comment: You looking for something other than the `&&` operator to combine multiple checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to write a function that uses a basic loop and returns a Boolean value. Get the value of each `input` field with `$('#fieldId')`, compare it with your expected answers, and then base the next action on the value returned by the answer-checking function. Based on your example snippet, here's one way to do it:

```
var fields = ['r1c1', 'r1c2', 'r1c3', 'r1c4', 'r1c5'],
    answers = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];

var checkAnswers = function(fieldArray, answerArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < fieldArray.length; i += 1) {
        if ($('#' + fieldArray[i] + '-input').val() !== answerArray[i]) {
            // This field doesn't have the correct answer
            return false;
        }
    }
    // Made it all the way through the loop, so all answers match
    return true;
}

if (checkAnswers(fields, answers)) {
    // dialog X
} else {
    // dialog Y
}
```